# Why 'this' object is assigned to a local variable in js

Tags: javascript, extjs

I was going through ext-all-debug.js file from extjs library  and most of the class methods had

```
var me = this;
```

How does it helps in performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't help with performance. It helps with confusion. `this` gets reassigned a lot, automatically. If you want to remember what `this` is, you assign it to something else, traditionally `me`, `self` or `that`. Or you use `bind`. It also helps with compression, since `me` can be compressed to a one-letter variable, but only `this` is magical and can't be renamed.

Comment: +1 for it the helps with confusion.  `var me = this` is a pet peeve of mine, instead of someone banging their head against their computer for 2 hours because in a special case where `me !== this` they could have refactored some duplicated code and cut down on the minified size that way.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't help in performace but when the function is called in a different scope you still have the pointer to the expected object

```
function someFunc() {
    var me = this;
    someElement.on("click", function() {
        console.log(me);
        console.log(this);
    });
};
```

when this is logged the console will show the caller of the function. In the case where me is logged it will show the element that was clicked on

Comment: Perhaps you could give an example with code to explain?

Comment: This is a proper use case for `var me = this` but just to be clear the Ext code base doesn't do `var me = this` for this reason.  They do it to aid minification, most of the time it is done `me` is not used in a closure.

Comment: Interesting, i didn't know it was used to aid minification. Never thought of it that way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not performance related. However by this way it declares a var that can be accessed by other members within this “Closure”. Noted that the "this" of the other members is not determined by the definition context, "this" is whoever calls the function. On the contrary, variant scope is always determined by the definition context.

Comment: More like a comment than answer.